# Unable to post-review from cvs commitinfo trigger in reviewboard

Tags: cvs, review-board

I am trying to use post review with every cvs commit. Applying a trigger in     cvs commitinfo file as follows
    $>cat commitinfo
    /usr/bin/post-review  --server=http://172.16.7.100:81   --username=admin --password=admin --submit-as=vineet  --repository-url=svn:/opt/cvsroot
    [user@svn test]$ cat .reviewboardrc
    REPOSITORY = 'svn:/opt/cvsroot'
    REVIEWBOARD_URL = 'http://172.16.37.170:81'

```
Repository Information in reviewboard dashboard

Path=svn:/opt/cvsroot
Mirror Path=svn:/opt/cvsroot

What error i get  is -

[user@svn test]$ cvs -d :pserver:kapilap@svn:/opt/cvsroot ci -m "BugID:47300 update" document.txt
Post-review for /opt/cvsroot/test
No supported repository could be accessed at the supplied url.

If i remove "--repository-url=svn:/opt/cvsroot" from commitinfo file i
get this error-

[kapila.narang@svn test]$ cvs -d :pserver:kapilap@svn:/opt/cvsroot ci -m "BugID:47300 update" document.txt
Post-review for /opt/cvsroot/test
The current directory does not contain a checkout from a
supported source code repository.

to Add more details-

[kapila.narang@svn test]$ cvs -d :pserver:kapilap@svn:/opt/cvsroot ci -m "BugID:47300 update" document.txt
Post-review for /opt/cvsroot/test
RBTools 0.4.1
Home = /home/kapilacvs

No supported repository could be accessed at the supplied url. 
Need urgent help pls expert help meeeeeeeeeee :(
```